# What do the green/red numbers at the right hand edge of a Github PR mean

Tags: github

[image]

What do the circled green/red numbers (and blocks) mean?

Answer (score 3):

This shows number of deletions and additions tracked by git.

Comment: Thank you. But can you be more specific? Deletions and additions of what? Lines? Characters? And what are the blocks?

Comment: Of course, line

Comment: So far as I know, it denote github repository.

Answer (score 0):

It displays the number of lines that have been added to and deleted from the source code.
In the GitHub repository, the blocks are the pieces of code, images, text, audio, and video files that are used to create a project.